# The panel is not showing up

Tags: 6, panels

I'm making my own custom panels **layout** using the Panels module for the front page of my site. This is how I have my page set up.

Two blocks will be displayed on all pages: a header, and a footer (each have their own navigation bar).  The header contains a few images (logo and two more) plus a customized login block (using the hook).  Now, I've decided to create my home page, which uses the clean URL /home. I've copied the files from the **twocol** folder in the **modules/panels/plugins/layouts** folder to a **twocol-bottom folder** in my layouts folder of my theme's root (I hope you guys can understand what that means: basically **/sites/all/themes/my_theme/layouts/twocol-bottom**).

I've renamed the twocol folder to twocol-bottom (because, I just want to add a bottom panel that extends the full length of the #main area (inside the #main-wrapper).  I've renamed all the files to twocol-bottom.css, twocol-bottom.inc, twocol-bottom.png, twocol-bottom.tpl.php. I've added the following line to my theme's info file:

```
plugins[panels][layouts] = layouts
```

#### twocol-bottom.inc

```
<?php

// Plugin definition
$plugin = array(
  'title' => t('twocol-bottom'),
  'category' => t('Columns: 2'),
  'icon' => 'twocol-bottom.png',
  'theme' => 'twocol-bottom',
  'css' => 'twocol-bottom.css',
  'panels' => array(
    'left' => t('Left side'),
    'right' => t('Right side'),
    'bottom' => t('Bottom pane')
  ),
);

?>
```

#### twocol-bottom.tpl.php

```
<div class="twocol-bottom-display panel-2col clear-block" 
<?php if (!empty($css_id)) {  print "id=\"$css_id\""; } ?>>
  <div class="twocol-bottom-panel panel-col-first">
    <div class="inside"><?php print $content['left']; ?></div>
  </div>

  <div class="twocol-bottom-panel panel-col-last">
    <div class="inside"><?php print $content['right']; ?></div>
  </div>

  <div class="twocol-bottom-bottom">
    <div class="inside"><?php print $content['bottom']; ?></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I changed all the CSS classes to match the classes in the .tpl.php file.

When I flush my cache in Drupal and choose to change the layout of my first panel, the newly added panel isn't showing up. I'm not sure how to make the panel show up.

Comment: You've made the question complected.

Comment: What Nikhil said. All I see is a wall of text and not a clear question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're taking the wrong approach.  One of the main reasons for using the Panels module is to avoid writing custom code like this.

Instead of making your own custom panels layout in code for just your front page, use the "Flexible" layout builder provided by Panels.  You can then use the layout designer to add rows, regions, and columns however you want.  You can even add CSS classes and choose between fluid and fixed widths, setting the percentages as you like.

Given that you can do all of that *within* the Panels module itself, I would think twice before you try to code a layout just for one page.